# Template instantiation reaches depth of 900

Tags: c++, recursion, c++17, variadic-templates, template-instantiation

In the following code I..

- create test list using my custom list struct (which works as expected)
- push some test ints into it
- want to call a function that takes as parameters every list element (`observe()`)

To achieve this I tried to recursively extract the function parameters (values of the list nodes) out of the list via the `call_observe_with_list` and `call_observe_with_list_impl` - helpers. However, this leads infinite template recursion:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/memory:81,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/bits/shared_ptr.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Yp, class> std::shared_ptr<list<int>::node>::shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&) [with _Yp = list<int>::node; <template-parameter-1-2> = <missing>]':
<source>:45:43:   recursively required from 'void call_observe_with_list_impl(const list<T>&, std::shared_ptr<typename list<T>::node>, const Ks& ...) [with T = int; Ks = {int}]'
<source>:45:43:   required from 'void call_observe_with_list_impl(const list<T>&, std::shared_ptr<typename list<T>::node>, const Ks& ...) [with T = int; Ks = {}]'
<source>:52:39:   required from 'void call_observe_with_list(const list<T>&) [with T = int; Ks = {}]'
<source>:65:37:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:245:9: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
         typename = _Constructible<const shared_ptr<_Yp>&>>
```

This is my code ([try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/rT6aPz9x8)).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct list
{
    struct node
    {
        T val_;
        std::shared_ptr<node> next_;
        node(T val, const std::shared_ptr<node>& next) : val_(val), next_(next) {}
    };

    std::shared_ptr<node> head_ = nullptr;

    void push(T val) {
        head_ = std::make_shared<node>(val, head_);
    }

    void erase(T val) {
        auto* pptr = &head_;
        for (auto node = head_; node; node = node->next_) {
            if (node->val_ == val) {
                *pptr = node->next_;
                return ;
            }
            pptr = &(node->next_);
        }
    }
};


template <typename... Ts>
void observe(Ts... Args)
{
    std::cout << "observe" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ks>
void call_observe_with_list_impl(const list<T>& some_list, std::shared_ptr<typename list<T>::node> curr_ptr, const Ks&... Args)
{
    if (curr_ptr == nullptr) {
        return observe(Args...);
    } else {
        return call_observe_with_list_impl(some_list, curr_ptr->next_, curr_ptr->val_, Args...);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void call_observe_with_list(const list<T>& some_list)
{
    return call_observe_with_list_impl(some_list, some_list.head_);
}

int main()
{
    list<int> some_list;

    some_list.push(1);
    some_list.push(2);
    some_list.push(10123);
    some_list.push(100);
    some_list.push(5);

    call_observe_with_list(some_list);
}
```

Why does this happen? The terminal condition (last node = nullptr) is always met so this shouldn't ever happen or what am I missing?

Comment: `if` does not stop the instantiation of the template.

Comment: @appleapple Sorry copy artifact, removed it :)

Comment: @康桓瑋 How? It checks if the ptr is null in which case it will terminate the recursion, no?

Comment: It will only be checked at *runtime*, however, the instantiation of the template is at *compile-time*, and the compiler has no way of knowing when to stop.

Comment: Each recursive call to `call_observe_with_list_impl` grows the template argument list by one. There is no exit condition for the template instantiation recursion. You probable want to limit the maximum number of arguments with which this can be called. how do you even call a method with 10 thousand or 10 million arguments at runtime?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Interesting. But what happens to the if in constexpr context? Is it just ignored? And why is `call_observe_with_list_impl()` called and not `observe()` then?

Comment: @user2407038 So it is not possible to decide the number of function arguments at runtime under any circumstances?

Comment: @glades It is possible to decide the number of arguments from some fixed number of arguments (say between 1 and 10 arguments). What is not possible is to write a function which takes arbitrarily many arguments, which is what you've done here; it is not even possible to write a single non templated function taking for example 10million args. You have to decide in advance what the maximum number of arguments you'll reasonable expect to call this method with; and what to do if you have more list elements than that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to decide the number of arguments from some fixed number of arguments (say between 1 and 10 arguments). What is not possible is to write a function which takes arbitrarily many arguments, which is what you've tried to do here. It is not even possible to write a single non-templated function taking 10 million arguments, for example - the runtime doesn't have functions which take arbitrarily many parameters.

You have to decide in advance what the maximum number of arguments you'll reasonable expect to call this method with; and what to do if you have more list elements than that.

The simplest solution is to ignore the call if there's too many arguments, but you could also throw an exception:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ks>
void call_observe_with_list_impl(const list<T>& some_list, std::shared_ptr<typename list<T>::node> curr_ptr, const Ks&... Args)
{
    if (curr_ptr == nullptr) {
        return observe(Args...);
    } else
    {
        // note the if "constexpr" here - when there's more than 10 args,
        // the `else' branch is not even instantiated
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Ks) >= 10)
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        else
        {
            return call_observe_with_list_impl(some_list, curr_ptr->next_, curr_ptr->val_, Args...);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also break the calls to `observe` into "chunks" of up to some fixed size:

```
        ...
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Ks) >= 10)
        {
            observe(Args...);
            call_observe_with_list_impl(some_list, curr_ptr->next_);
        }
        ...
```

Then for example the following program:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void comma_sep(T Arg0, Ts... Args)
{
    std::cout << Arg0;
    ((std::cout << ", " << Args), ...);
}

template <typename... Ts>
void observe(Ts... Args)
{
    std::cout << "observe(";
    comma_sep(Args...);
    std::cout << ")\n";
}

int main()
{
    list<int> some_list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        some_list.push(i*i);
    }

    call_observe_with_list(some_list);
}
```

gives this output:

```
observe(225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576)
observe(16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169)
observe(0, 1, 4)
```